# Woocommerce how to show custom attributes other than default in home page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes

After a long and recursive search on the web, I didn't find a solution for my needs.

I need to display, in home page, not only product name and price, but also some custom attribute I already have set in all my products. Let's say 'year' and 'author'.

All snippets found are single product or shop page related only, nothing for home page (or any other page anyway).
Tried also with woocommerce shortcodes, but they are not applicable for that purpose.

I already use:
[recent_products per_page="6" columns="6" orderby="year" order="desc"]
to display recent products ordered by "year" att (I found a snippet to add 'orderby' custom att).

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code that you can use for displaying products from a specific category with meta data on the home page:

```
<ul class="products">
        <?php
            $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'product_cat' => 'categoryNAme', 'orderby' => 'rand' );
            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; ?>
                    <li class="product">    

                        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $loop->post->ID ) ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr($loop->post->post_title ? $loop->post->post_title : $loop->post->ID); ?>">

                            <?php woocommerce_show_product_sale_flash( $post, $product ); ?>

                            <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID )) echo get_the_post_thumbnail($loop->post->ID, 'shop_catalog'); else echo '<img src="'.woocommerce_placeholder_img_src().'" alt="Placeholder" width="300px" height="300px" />'; ?>


                            <h3>Title: <?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                            <h3>Content: <?php the_content(); ?></h3>
                            <h3>Date: <?php the_date(); ?></h3>
                            <h3>Author: <?php the_author(); ?></h3>

                            <span class="price"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></span>                    

                        </a>

                        <?php woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart( $loop->post, $product ); ?>

                    </li>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
    </ul><!--/.products-->
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Adding php code in wordpress pages is a nightmare. I've tried with few plugins but it seems that html and php mixed are not supported. So I've tried to use your code as a page template, and after hacking some field (attribute in place of category and year as orderby) I got finally an output. Unfortunately, this doesn't help so much, because the php output section (the_author etc.) uses php variables, not custom attributes. as needed. I'm not skilled in php in wp, so if you have further ideas it would be great! Thanks.